# Angular 4 + Spring MVC sample project structure

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc

Can someone provide a link or some information how to create a JAVA Spring MVC and Angular 4 Project. I have been doing research for a long time. Hope someone can share their research or experience.

Answer (score 0):

This site really very good for `Spring`, `Hibernate` and `Angular JS` purpose.

[Visit Here](http://websystique.com/)

Answer (score 0):

***No perfect answers till now thats fine, I got solution. How I did ?***

You need 2 contexts.
(1) Angular 2 project and
(2) Spring MVC

Follow below steps to achieve our main goal, to run SPRINGMVC + Angular2 on a single server.

Create normal Dynamic web project.
Add all dependancy required for spring or user maven pom.xml
Open CMD, navigate to angular2 application. Hit command
npm install

and then

ng build or use ng build

use ng build (hyphen)(hyphen)prod for production build.
this command will create a “dist” folder, copy all files including all folders.

4. Paste those files and folders into WebContent directory.
5. Last thing, you need to change basehref=”./” in index.html.

See this Image => It contains details about File structure for springMVC+ANGULAR2/4/5
Now you are ready to run server or you can deploy war file and serve it with tomcat or other servers.
If you are using Rest webservices and want to run angular2 and spring in a single server, You need to put webServiceEndPointUrl as per your host url. For example, If you are running app on localhost:8080, you need to keep url
webServiceEndPointUrl= “http://localhost:8080/api/user"; at angular side. After that you can build and copy paste to your WebContent folder.

I know there are many drawbacks to use these way for running application on a single server, but if it must required you can follow this.

If you change anything at angular side, you need to build and copy-paste dist folder all time and then you can deploy it!

Visit : Run Spring4MVC with Angular 2 on a single server, I have mentioned file structure

I know there are many drawbacks to use these way for running application on a single server, but if it must required you can follow this.

If you change anything at angular side, you need to copy paste dist folder all time and then you can deploy it!

Download or clone example : Github, You can fork and star repository.

**#Edit-1:**

In Angular 2/4/5, You can keep basehref=”./” by default. While building project (as dev/prod build) it will keep ./ in index.html as it is. Previously it was not working like that thing.

If you are running your angular 2 app on lets say localhost:4200 then it will refer basehref=”/” you can find basehref attribute in src/app/index.html . Now if you want to run this with springMVC (normal configurations * pattern), you will put all files of dist folder to webapps or WebContent folder. Here you need to say from where spring can start rendering. [(dot-slash)./ means the current directory] [(slash) / is the root directory]. If you have another configurations, you may skip it. In general architecture I have tried and implemented successfully. Even you can try with / and ./

Comment: It's hard to see if there is an actual answer in here somewhere. This needs some [edit]ing for brevity. Don't mark edits in the text. Keep it simple. Explain the caveats and limitations.